# How to collaborate developing an app without using an App Store Connect Team?

Tags: ios-appstore, xcode, app-store-connect

My friend and I have personal iCloud accounts that we use to develop apps in our free time.

When he clones to his computer and runs, he gets errors with the team, bundle identifier, and push notifications.

We don't have a company, so I can't create a team and assign roles. How do we collaborate with each other if we can't make a team?

Apparently you need to show proof of a company to Apple to create a Team account.

Is there no way for hobbyists to easily collaborate on a project? There is surprisingly little on this topic online.

Comment: There are a lot of open source applications built and they don't use Team accounts. Look into what they do.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts. I'll probably be posting in the issues for these open source apps

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. This is quite broad and we strongly prefer one question per question. If you look over our [tour] it has some tips on doing some research and if you edited in what research you did to solve this, even if it’s not helping - showing your work helps us help you right where you got stuck. Expanding on ***There is surprisingly little on this topic online.*** with anything you tried would make a great edit I think.